# Matlab signal plot ,not expected X axis

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, filter, signals

I got a 2d array ,that each row represents a signal (for wiener filtering)

```
      Arr(10,45).
```

I want to plot,all signals (all column) in same figure, with X axis the K coefficient of wiener fieltering that is

```
      K=(-11:0.5:11);
```

Which is of size=45.I also want it to be with logarithmic in both axis , x and y.
          But when i plot  with[image]

```
      loglog(Arr.'); 
      set(gca,'xtick',(-11:0.5:11);
```

The result is not what i need.
What's going on?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When plotting it, you should specify the `k` values as the first input to `plot` and `Arr.'` as the second. If you do not do this, MATLAB will simply use `1:size(Arr, 2)` as the x coordinates of your plot.

```
hplot = plot(k, Arr.');
```

Comment: in your previous answer you posted that for naming i should do this :

Comment: hplot=plot(abs(log2(k)),log2(error.'));
set(hplot, {'Color'}, num2cell(parula(size(Arr, 1)), 2))                                               How is this changing with  plot(k,Arr.') now?

Comment: @alphonse It remains the same.

Comment: Value cell array andle dimension must match handle vector length                          Anyway , thanks for your time

Comment: You need to use `set(hplot, {'Color'}, num2cell(parula(size(error, 1)), 2))` instead since you're plotting `log2(error.')` not `Arr.'`